# Using ViewPager together with GestureListener?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I downloaded a Java class named SimpleGestureListener which was created by a user named CoXier.

```
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.GestureDetector;
  import android.view.MotionEvent;
  public class SimpleGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
      private static final String TAG = "SimpleGestureListener";
      private Listener mListener;

  @Override
  public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
      return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
      Log.i(TAG,e1.toString()+"\n"+e2.toString());
      Log.d(TAG,"distanceX = "+distanceX+",distanceY = "+distanceY);
      if (mListener == null)
          return true;

      if (distanceX == 0 && Math.abs(distanceY) > 1){
          mListener.onScrollVertical(distanceY);
      }

      if (distanceY == 0 && Math.abs(distanceX) > 1){
          mListener.onScrollHorizontal(distanceX);
      }
      return true;
  }


  public void setListener(Listener mListener) {
      this.mListener = mListener;
  }

  interface Listener{
      /**
       * left scroll dx >0
       * right scroll dx <0
       * @param dx
       */
      void onScrollHorizontal(float dx);

      /**
       * upward scroll dy > 0
       * downward scroll dy < 0
       * @param dy
       */
      void onScrollVertical(float dy);
  }
```

}

When using it in an app which consists of 1 activity only, it works flawlessly.
For example, here I can change the background color of the layout by using horizonal or vertical swiping:
(I disabled the horizontal swiping functionality afterwards)

```
  import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.GestureDetector;
  import android.view.MotionEvent;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
  {
      private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
      private GestureDetector mDetector;
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          SimpleGestureListener simpleGestureListener = new SimpleGestureListener();
          simpleGestureListener.setListener(new SimpleGestureListener.Listener()
          {
              @Override
              public void onScrollHorizontal(float dx)
              {

          }
          @Override
          public void onScrollVertical(float dy)
          {

              ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraint_layout);
              if (dy > 0)
              {
                  constraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
              }
              if (dy < 0)
              {
                  constraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
              }
          }
      });
      mDetector = new GestureDetector(this, simpleGestureListener);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
  {
      mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
      return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }
```

}

Now my problem is that I would like to use this in my original app which consists of fragments and a ViewPager.
I would like to add this SwipeUp/Down functionality inside of 1 fragment.
(I don't need it for the other fragments.)

What would I have to include inside of my fragment class?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Page_2 extends Fragment
{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View PageTwo = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2, container, false);
        return PageTwo;
    }
}
```

Do I have to make my MainActivity.java the same way as code block 2?
(The example app)
Currently, my MainActivity.java looks like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.GestureDetector;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
        ViewPager vp;
        private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
        private static GestureDetector mDetector;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            SimpleGestureListener simpleGestureListener = new SimpleGestureListener();
            simpleGestureListener.setListener(new SimpleGestureListener.Listener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onScrollHorizontal(float dx)
                {
                    Log.wtf("swipe", "horizontal = " + dx);
                }
                @Override
                public void onScrollVertical(float dy)
                {
                    Log.wtf("swipe", "vertical = " + dy);
                }
            });
            mDetector = new GestureDetector(this, simpleGestureListener);

            ViewPager vp = findViewById(R.id.vp);
            SetUpViewPager(vp);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
            mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        public void SetUpViewPager(ViewPager viewpage)
        {
            MyViewPagerAdapter Adapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            Adapter.AddPageFragment(new Page_1(), "Page 1"); // Load pages inside of ViewPager
            Adapter.AddPageFragment(new Page_2(), "Page 2");
            Adapter.AddPageFragment(new Page_3(), "Page 3");
            Adapter.AddPageFragment(new Page_5(), "Page 5");
            viewpage.setAdapter(Adapter);
        }
        public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
        {
            private List<Fragment> MyFragment = new ArrayList<>();
            private List<String> MyPageTitle = new ArrayList<>();

            public MyViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager)
            {
                super(manager);
            }
            public void AddPageFragment(Fragment Frag, String Title)
            {
                MyFragment.add(Frag);
                MyPageTitle.add(Title);
            }
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int i)
            {
                return MyFragment.get(i);
            }
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
            {
                return MyPageTitle.get(position);
            }
            @Override
            public int getCount()
            {
                return 4; // 4 pages total
            }
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
        {
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.action_settings)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

I believe that most of this code (which is related to the GestureDetector) has to be in Page_2?
Probably I also have to use

```
mDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), simpleGestureListener);
```

in Page_2, because otherwise it will not find it.

Anyway, whatever I tried, it never worked the way as in the single activity test app.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you were just doing some test, there are something bigger than just changing the background color by scroll to left or right.
I dont know. I just give my suggestion with the code you offer.

There is a [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener).
It is much like the Adapter or ClickListener is ListView to tell you which page/item is calling the method.

You can simply follow the page-change index to know pager swinging to left or right.

```
int lastPosition = 0;
void onPageSelected(int position) {
   if(position < lastPosition);
   else if(position > lastPosition);

   lastPosition = position;
}
```

By the way, I didn't test my code. But I just used ViewPager.OnPageChangedListener today.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Ok so this means instead of trying to use a ViewPager + this SimpleGestureListener, I can just use the ViewPager.OnPageChangedListener to use horizontal swipe (changing views) + vertical swipe (adding function)? Will the vertical swipe then work on ANY fragment?

Comment: It can definitely work on ANY fragment. If you really know how.

Comment: But I didn't get your point. I thought you want to change something with the pager swipe. So you need another solution. Wait....
The TouchEventListener of ViewPager should be overwrite. You need to make your own ViewPager.

Comment: Hi, The ViewPager functionality is ok as it is! The only thing I would like to have additionally is a swipe up/swipe down functionality for 1 fragment. Basically it's indepenent of the ViewPager. However, it might be needed to create an own ViewPager (as you said). Well, any advice how? :)

Comment: You need a switch in the ViewPager to tell the GestureDetector "it is time to detect scroll-Y-changing."
Still, I can not sure what you really  want to do about the Y-changing. IT IS A VIEWPAGER ALREADY.
If there is a Scroll in Fragment2. Then you can set scrollChangeListener in that Scroll. No need for these... But I dont know.